# Form Doesn't Post Value in OrangeHRM

Tags: php, oop, doctrine, symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I create new module on OrangeHRM and try to create a form. But when i post the form, the values doesn't post to action file. I've tried many times, but the result still same.

here is the action:

```
<?php

class requestTrainingAction extends sfAction {

    private $trainingService;

    /**
     * Get TrainingService
     * @returns TrainingService
     */
    public function getTrainingService() {
        if (is_null($this->trainingService)) {
            $this->trainingService = new TrainingService();
        }

        return $this->trainingService;
    }

    /**
     * Set TrainingService
     * @param TrainingService $trainingService
     */
    public function setTrainingService(TrainingService $trainingService) {
        $this->trainingService = $trainingService;
    }

    /**
    * @param sfForm $form
    * @return
    */
    public function setForm(sfForm $form) {
        if (is_null($this->form)) {
            $this->form = $form;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param <type> $request
     */
    public function execute($request) {

        /* For highlighting corresponding menu item */
        $request->setParameter('initialActionName', 'requestTraining');

        $this->form = new RequestTrainingForm();

        if ($this->getUser()->hasFlash('templateMessage')) {
            $this->templateMessage = $this->getUser()->getFlash('templateMessage');
        }        

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {

            $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));

            if ($this->form->isValid()) {

                $templateMessage = $this->form->save();
                $this->getUser()->setFlash($templateMessage['messageType'], $templateMessage['message']);                
                $this->redirect('training/requestTraining');

            }

        }
        $this->listForm = new DefaultListForm();
    }

}

?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<?php

class RequestTrainingForm extends BaseForm {

    private $trainingService;
    private $trainingId;

    public function getTrainingService() {
        if (is_null($this->trainingService)) {
            $this->trainingService = new TrainingService();
        }
        return $this->trainingService;
    }

    public function setTrainingService(TrainingService $trainingService) {
        $this->trainingService = $trainingService;
    }

    public function configure() {


        // Job Level
        $jobLevelChoices = Training::getLevelTextList();
        $divisionChoices = Training::getDivisionTextList();
        $departmentChoices = Training::getDepartmentTextList();

        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'chkJobLevel' => new ohrmWidgetCheckboxGroup(array('choices' => $jobLevelChoices, 'show_all_option' => true)),
            'chkDivision' => new ohrmWidgetCheckboxGroup(array('choices' => $divisionChoices, 'show_all_option' => true)),
            'chkDepartment' => new ohrmWidgetCheckboxGroup(array('choices' => $departmentChoices, 'show_all_option' => true)),
            'training_name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'training_desc' => new sfWidgetFormTextArea(),
        ));

        $this->setValidators(array(
            'chkJobLevel' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($jobLevelChoices), 'required' => true, 'multiple' => true)),
            'chkDivision' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($divisionChoices), 'required' => true, 'multiple' => true)),
            'chkDepartment' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($departmentChoices), 'required' => true, 'multiple' => true)),
            'training_name' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true, 'max_length' => 120)),
            'training_desc' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false, 'max_length' => 400)),
        ));

        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('training[%s]');

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStylesheets() {
        $styleSheets = parent::getStylesheets();

        return $styleSheets;
    }

    public function getJavaScripts() {
        $javaScripts = parent::getJavaScripts();
        $javaScripts[] = plugin_web_path('orangehrmTrainingPlugin', 'js/requestTrainingSuccess.js');

        return $javaScripts;
    }

    public function save() {

        $message = array('messageType' => 'success', 'message' => __(TopLevelMessages::SAVE_SUCCESS));
        $training = new Training();

        $training->setTrainingName($this->getValue('training_name'));
        $training->setTrainingDesc($this->getValue('training_desc'));
        $this->getTrainingService()->saveRequestTraining($training);

        return $message;

    }

}

?>
```

And here the DAO:

```
<?php

class TrainingDao extends BaseDao {

    public function saveRequestTraining(Training $training) {
        try {
            $training->save();

            return $training;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new DaoException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

The error show this:

```
01/06/17 11:21:16,781 [644] ERROR filter.ExceptionCatcherFilter - Uncaught Exception: exception 'Doctrine_Validator_Exception' with message 'Validation failed in class Training

  2 fields had validation errors:

    * 1 validator failed on trainingName (unsigned)
    * 1 validator failed on trainingDesc (unsigned)
' in C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Transaction.php:265
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php(1395): Doctrine_Transaction->commit(NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php(148): Doctrine_Connection->commit()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Record.php(1718): Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveGraph(Object(Training))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\lib\dao\TrainingDao.php(7): Doctrine_Record->save()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\lib\service\TrainingService.php(43): TrainingDao->saveRequestTraining(Object(Training))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\lib\form\RequestTrainingForm.php(79): TrainingService->saveRequestTraining(Object(Training))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\modules\training\actions\requestTrainingAction.class.php(87): RequestTrainingForm->save()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(952): requestTrainingAction->execute(Object(sfWebRequest))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmCorePlugin\lib\filter\orangehrmExecutionFilter.php(36): sfExecutionFilter->executeAction(Object(requestTrainingAction))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(947): orangehrmExecutionFilter->executeAction(Object(requestTrainingAction))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(933): sfExecutionFilter->handleAction(Object(sfFilterChain), Object(requestTrainingAction))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfExecutionFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\filter\sfCommonFilter.class.php(29): sfFilterChain->execute()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfCommonFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmCorePlugin\lib\filter\orangehrmPostExecutionFilter.php(22): sfFilterChain->execute()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): orangehrmPostExecutionFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\ModuleFilter.php(56): sfFilterChain->execute()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ModuleFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmCorePlugin\lib\authorization\filter\ohrmAuthorizationFilter.php(97): sfFilterChain->execute()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ohrmAuthorizationFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\SessionInfoFetcherFilter.php(67): sfFilterChain->execute()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): SessionInfoFetcherFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\OrangeI18NFilter.php(58): sfFilterChain->execute()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): OrangeI18NFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\ExceptionCatcherFilter.php(26): sfFilterChain->execute()
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ExceptionCatcherFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\filter\sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php(72): sfFilterChain->execute()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(995): sfFilterChain->execute()
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfRenderingFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(665): sfFilterChain->execute()
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(2352): sfController->forward('training', 'requestTraining')
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php(170): sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\web\index.php(22): sfContext->dispatch()
#34 {main}

Next exception 'DaoException' with message 'Validation failed in class Training

  2 fields had validation errors:

    * 1 validator failed on trainingName (unsigned)
    * 1 validator failed on trainingDesc (unsigned)
' in C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\lib\dao\TrainingDao.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\lib\service\TrainingService.php(43): TrainingDao->saveRequestTraining(Object(Training))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\lib\form\RequestTrainingForm.php(79): TrainingService->saveRequestTraining(Object(Training))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmTrainingPlugin\modules\training\actions\requestTrainingAction.class.php(87): RequestTrainingForm->save()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(952): requestTrainingAction->execute(Object(sfWebRequest))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmCorePlugin\lib\filter\orangehrmExecutionFilter.php(36): sfExecutionFilter->executeAction(Object(requestTrainingAction))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(947): orangehrmExecutionFilter->executeAction(Object(requestTrainingAction))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(933): sfExecutionFilter->handleAction(Object(sfFilterChain), Object(requestTrainingAction))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfExecutionFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\filter\sfCommonFilter.class.php(29): sfFilterChain->execute()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfCommonFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmCorePlugin\lib\filter\orangehrmPostExecutionFilter.php(22): sfFilterChain->execute()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): orangehrmPostExecutionFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\ModuleFilter.php(56): sfFilterChain->execute()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ModuleFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmCorePlugin\lib\authorization\filter\ohrmAuthorizationFilter.php(97): sfFilterChain->execute()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ohrmAuthorizationFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\SessionInfoFetcherFilter.php(67): sfFilterChain->execute()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): SessionInfoFetcherFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\OrangeI18NFilter.php(58): sfFilterChain->execute()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): OrangeI18NFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\apps\orangehrm\lib\filter\ExceptionCatcherFilter.php(26): sfFilterChain->execute()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ExceptionCatcherFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\filter\sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php(72): sfFilterChain->execute()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(995): sfFilterChain->execute()
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfRenderingFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(665): sfFilterChain->execute()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\cache\orangehrm\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php(2352): sfController->forward('training', 'requestTraining')
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php(170): sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm-3.2.1\symfony\web\index.php(22): sfContext->dispatch()
#30 {main}
```

Comment: Solved, the problem is because i wrote boolean between quote (') in the baseRequestTraining file